# Pass date from airflow dag to a task

Tags: python-3.x, datetime, airflow, mwaa

I am using SSHOperator in airflow dag ( I am using AWS MWAA service for airflow). It is executing a shell script. I need to pass current date and time in format %Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f%z to the script.

I do not have Pendulam package available in my airflow so I am trying to use datetime.
I tried passing the date using `datetime.datetime.utcnow().strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f%z')` but it fails.

I also tried to print it directly in dag ( like below) but this doesn't work either.

```
print(datetime.datetime.utcnow().strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f%z'))
```

Can someone please suggest how to pass current date in this format to shell script.

Comment: Can you share the error you are getting and add it to the post?

Comment: and `dag` example